# Jquery and ASCX control rendered multiple times on a page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery

I have an ascx control which contains dropdownboxes I want to be able to reset with JavaScript.
Because the ascx control is rendered multiple times on the aspx page, I programatically add a distinguishing field to each dropdown such as this in the code behind of the ascx:

```
var g = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
DropDownListBool.Attributes.Add("jqID", "ddBool" + g);
DropDownListEqual.Attributes.Add("jqID", "ddEq" + g);
```

On the rendered page, when I want to reset the dropdowns for one of the controls, I have a hyperlink which invokes a javascript function with g as an argument.

In the javascript, using jquery, I try to get both dropdowns for one specific ascx control like this:

```
function clearControl(g) {
var dds = $("select[jqID = 'dd\\S*" + g + "']");
}
```

I then do:

```
jQuery.each(dds, function(i, val) { val.select = 0; });
```

Should this work? Right now it is resetting seemingly random dropdown boxes.
Is there perhaps a limit to attribute length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have better luck with a different selector, say the "[ends with](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue)" attribute selector.

```
var dds = $("select[jqID$='" + g + "']");
```

If you needed to select based on starting with `dd` and ending with the value of `g`, you could use a filter and utilize both "ends with" and "[starts with](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue)";

```
var dds = $("select[jqID^='dd']").filter( "[jqID$='" + g + '']");
```

As far as I know you can't use a regular expression when using the attribute equals selector.  I'm surprised it works for you at all.